# How to write a function that allocate a complete data structure

Tags: c, malloc

As I wrote above I'm trying to write a function that allocate a data structure

here is what I have done but when I'm trying to call the T with an index it throws an error

```
typedef struct {
    float *tab;
    int nbCases;
}dyntab;

void initDyn(dyntab *dtab, int size){
    dtab=malloc(size*sizeof(dyntab));
}

int main(){
    dyntab T;
    initDyn(&T, 10); // for example allocating a table with 10 cases
}
```

it throws an error

subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you are allocating memory with `dyntab` that too for local variable having leaks.

```
void initDyn(dyntab *dtab, int size){
    dtab=malloc(size*sizeof(dyntab));
}
```

Maybe you wanted

```
void initDyn(dyntab *dtab, int size){
    dtab->tab=malloc(size*sizeof(float));
    dtab->nbCases = size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use VLAs.

```
typedef struct {
    size_t nbCases;
    float tab[];
}dyntab;

dyntab *allocdyntab(dyntab *d, size_t size)
{
    dyntab *temp = realloc(d, size * sizeof(d -> tab[0]) + sizeof(*d));

    if(temp) 
    {
        temp -> nbCases = size;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

when you pass the NULL it will allocate new memory, if not it will reallocate the memory

```
int main(){
    dyntab *T = NULL;
    T = allocdyntab(T, 10); // for example allocating a table with 10 cases
    /*or*/
    //dyntab *T = allocdyntab(NULL, 10);

    /* another code */

    T = allocdyntab(T, 50); // change the size of already alllocated one without loosing the content 
    //you should add the temp variable and check the allocation result.

}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I do not believe that anyone learning C in 2019 will ever had to use pre C99 standard.

Comment: definitelly 2019 C learners  use this SDK:)

Comment: Yep, and note `tab` it is a FAM (Flexible Array Member) instead of a VLA `:)`,

Answer (score 1):

Doing

> ```
> void initDyn(dyntab *dtab, int size){
>     dtab=malloc(size*sizeof(dyntab));
> }
> ```

you only assign the local var *dtab* with the result of the *malloc*, there is no effect out of *initDyn*

Note it is better to not have effect out of *initDyn* because on the caller side *T* is a local variable, not a pointer

If you want to retrieve the array you can use the return value :

```
dyntab * initDyn(int size){
    return malloc(size*sizeof(dyntab));
}

int main(){
    dyntab * T = initDyn(10); // for example allocating a table with 10 cases
}
```

or use an output variable :

```
void initDyn(dyntab **dtab, int size){
    *dtab=malloc(size*sizeof(dyntab));
}

int main(){
    dyntab * T;
    initDyn(&T, 10); // for example allocating a table with 10 cases
}
```

Probably you also want to set *nbCases* with the number of elements ?